# how to count databases in mysql ending with a particular name

Tags: php, mysql, count

What i am trying to do , is to count the number of databases in mysql with php, i've got a few databses with name like corga_001, savage_900, bun_876, abc_999 , efg_999, hig_999.(i only want to count the total numbers of databases which have _999 at the end of it.

```
$id = 999;
$res = mysqli_query($conn,"SHOW DATABASES");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
echo count(strrchr($row['Database'],_ . $id) . "\n");}
```

the above code doesnt give me the total count of database names ending with _999 but gives me one count at a time as it is in a loop, all i want to do is to get the total count of database names ending with _999.Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
"SHOW DATABASES WHERE `Database` LIKE '$baseid\_%'";
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: with the above code, i was able to select databases with 999_ in the begining of the databse name

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = 999;

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, 'SHOW DATABASES LIKE CONCAT("%_", ?)')
{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    echo mysqli_num_rows($stmt);
}
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ongrass\profile\db\dbsignins\createdb.php on line 27

Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ongrass\profile\db\dbsignins\createdb.php on line 28

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ongrass\profile\db\dbsignins\createdb.php on line 30

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by just running this query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM information_schema.schemata
WHERE schema_name LIKE "%_999";
```